# How to approach a producer-consumer solution using threads in springboot

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, producer-consumer

I have gone through some `Spring` [documentation](https://www.baeldung.com/thread-pool-java-and-guava) to find out how i can simulate the producer-consumer solution, and I've found out that `Spring` can handle `Threads` like so:

[image]

Things start to get confusing when i'd like to make this kind of call `Asyncronous` and `notify` all consumers.

---

### My approach so far without Threads

I've got a `@Controller` where i make a `Synchronous` call to my `database` to grab all the data i need.

```java
@GetMapping("/manageEvents")
public String getManage(Model model, HttpServletResponse response) {
 List < Event > events = eventsRepo.findAll();
 model.add("events",events);
 return "manageEvents"
}
```

The `manageEvents.html` contains an `Ajax` call to an endpoint to get all **new** `Events` ,so in case there is a new one , i'm showing it as a `pop-up` to the current logged-in `User` through `JavaScript`.

---

### Goal

As you may have thought, my goal is this **new** `Event` to be added to the `Thread Pool` and immediately show it in my `html` as a `pop-up` and who ever grabs it first, can manage it (like a task assignment).

> Spring also provides an [Async](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async) annotation which i can use.

---

How can i approach this solution by using Threads?

Comment: I think you're mixing things up. A `ExecutorService` is used when you want to automatically queue programmatic tasks for execution. There is no user interaction involved

Comment: i see, how should i approach it?

Comment: Have you considered Server Sent Events (SSE)?  The clients subscribe to a server endpoint. When the server gets a new Event, it can send the notification (SSE) to all subscribed clients.  Your client can act on that event accordingly.

Comment: @IanMc haven't considered it at all, do you mean this example ? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events

Comment: I have not used WebFlux - I use SseEmitter.  Conceptually you want to create a server endpoint which maintains a List<SseEmitter> (each browser subscribes and represents a new emitter.  When the Event happens, you invoke emitter.send(...), and the browser receives that event.  Perhaps WebFlux makes this easier, I don't know.

Comment: i think your suggestion will work for me, although, how will i handle with my `Event` repository? So i guess there should be a stream in my `POST` endpoint, like you described so i can catch every incoming `Event`

Comment: What logic is saving a new Event (eventsRepo.save())?  It is in that code that you would fire a new SSE event.

Comment: I see , but that endpoint is protected with a `JWT` , this shouldn't be an issue right? I'll fire it as usual and catch it on an `endpoint` and access it with `JavaScript`

Comment: @IanMc i tried it manually, im returning and `SseEmitter` on `/score`  and in it i'm submitting the sseEmitter object to the executorService , and i'm listening to `/score`  via `JavaScript` , works fine! i think it's what i'm looking for! , thank you Ian, now i'll find out how to manage it/remove it from the pool

Comment: Great news. Good luck!  Let us know how you make out.